# is it recommended to use html2pdf script?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf, html2pdf

i have a php page, where is contains the full webpage on how i want things to go, now is it possible that with a php page that contains mysql and ajax to work with html2pdf script to convert the page into PDF if not what do you recommend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also check out mpdf, html2df is good, and I've used it, but this one is great and works in many complicated environments. FPDF is also a nice choice. You have many of them!

best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

`html2pdf` is **fine** if your HTML is *not very complicated*. I have used it in many apps and it works like a charm.

Comment: its a bit complicated, there are many tables, and also there is mysql inquiries